# php get the value of attribute name from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array stored in my database. So when I try : `print_r($arrayname)`,

It showed the result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Color,Processor
    [attribute_name] => Color,Processor
)
```

I want to get the values of `[attribute_name] => Color,Processor` .

So far I made the `foreach` loop like this :

```
  foreach ($arraylist as $name) {
    echo $name['attribute_name];
  }
```

But it showing the result like cc. So can someone kindly tell me how to get the values from database?

Comment: did you make a typo or are you running the code with echo $name['attribute_name];  (missing closing quote)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need to use foreach
You can access it like this.

```
echo $arraylist["attribute_name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
  foreach ($arraylist as $key => $name) {
    if($key == 'attribute_name')
        echo $name;
  }
```

Comment: It is repeating the values..like Color,ProcessorColor,Processor

Comment: Pls check your array with print_r($arraylist);
Or just use echo $arraylist["attribute_name"];